# How to copy a table schema with sql based on existance of the table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to duplicate a table schema, but only if the target table does not yet exist:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table_secondary as select * from my_table_primary
```

Problem: running this if the `my_secondary_table` exists results in:
`ERROR: Syntaxerror at "as"`.

What could I do to make this sql statement work?
(postgres 9.4)

Comment: Is this really a Java question?

Answer (score 0):

To duplicate the *schema* of a table, you need a completely different syntax.

```
create table if not exists my_table_secondary (
  like my_table_primary including all
);
```

> INCLUDING ALL is an abbreviated form of INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING
>   CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING STORAGE INCLUDING COMMENTS.

It doesn't duplicate foreign key constraints. See [CREATE TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtable.html). Search for "The LIKE clause".

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS SELECT * FROM my_table_primary;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table_secondary LIKE my_view;

INSERT INTO my_table_secondary 
SELECT * FROM my_view 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM my_table_secondary );
```

More on CREATE TABLE ... LIKE: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html